# Is it safe to eat raw green beans which have been in brine at room temperature?

Tags: food-safety, beans, brining

I've had some raw green beans in a brine solution for about one week at room temperature. Are they at risk for botulism? Can I put them into a vinegar solution and pickle them, or should I cook them first?

Comment: What type of brine solution, and what were you attempting to accomplish?

Comment: https://www.pinterest.com/recipes/pickled-string-beans/

Answer (score 2):

If you are at about 3-4% salt or higher and this sat around for a week, you probably have some lacto-fermented green beans.  They are technically pickled. Botulism will not thrive in a salt/acid environment.